# Determining if a node stream is in objectMode

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

Given a node js stream object how do I determine if it is an object stream in objectMode?

Say I have a readable stream instance

```
 const myReadableStream = new ReadableStreamImplementation({
  options: { objectMode : true }
});
```

How can I determine that the myReadableStream is in objectMode. Is there a method or property that can be read? Could not find the answer from skimming through node streams documentation.

**EDIT** Is there a way to tell without tapping into the stream and given only the stream object itself?

Comment: What is `objectMode`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I should think you could check the data as it comes in, it's either an object /string/or Buffer..

Comment: Is there a way to tell without tapping into the stream and given only the stream object itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it's a ReadableStream, you can check `stream._readableState.objectMode`.

Comment: The exact variable to check is `stream._readableState.objectMode`. Note that its use should be avoided when possible (see [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/445))

Comment: This prop is no more exposed in latest Node versions.

Answer (score 0):

From https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/stream.html#readablereadableobjectmode

```js
readable.readableObjectMode
Added in: v12.3.0

returns <boolean>
```

Getter for the property `objectMode` of a given Readable stream.

---

Similarly `writableObjectMode` is the property to check for Writable streams:
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/stream.html#writablewritableobjectmode

---

A [Duplex stream](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/stream.html#class-streamduplex) has both `readableObjectMode` and `writableObjectMode` as it contains both readable and writable streams.